# How to write a good request spec for #index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, request, rspec-rails

I am new to TDD and really enjoy it. **I am using RSpec.**

I am trying to learn to write good request specs (in general) and can find very little written on how to test the index method.

I have found this article: https://medium.com/@lcriswell/rails-api-request-specs-with-rspec-effeac468c4e, but I am not interested in testing an API, but an application with views.

What should I include on my index request tests **and why**?

Answer (score 0):

The first spec in the article is great, you can use it in testing a regular controller for responses.

If you are using any sort of authorization(e.g cancancan), you can test the same request for multiple types of users and check if you get a redirect or a success(you might have to mock the sign-in).

For testing the views that are being rendered, you can try this:

```
it { is_expected.to render_template(:index) }
```

If your action assigns instance variables, you can test out that the variable is a certain value like so:

```
expect(assigns(:foo)).to be true
```

If your action responds to different formats(HTML, json, ...), you can write different contexts for each of the formats, each time by changing the request(hint: for JS in your specs submit your request like so: `get :index, xhr: true`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Farhah :). When you are writing index tests, what are you writing and why? [as in you personally]

Comment: I write the cases as above; response spec to test the behavior expected when someone requests the index and test response of redirect, e.g unauthorized user. If the template has a different name instead of the default, test that it will render the template with the specified name, the spec for the assigns is used for any instance variables that get assigned e.g: index for students and I assign @students = Student.last(10), test students are the last 10 students, if I have a flash, I test what kind of flash and message. if there is a custom behavior, you have to test that out :) good luck!